# prevent overlapping bars using seaborn with pandas plotting

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, ipython, seaborn

I am trying to use pandas plotting to create a stacked horizontal barplot with a seaborn import. I would like to remove space between the bars, but also not have the bars overlap. This is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 3))
df.plot.barh(stacked=True, width=1)
```

[image]

This seems to work without importing seaborn, though I like the seaborn style and it is usually an import in the ipython notebook I am working in is this possible?

Comment: *" I would like to remove space between the bars, but also not have the bars overlap"* --> It's not clear to me how the image you posted doesn't satisfy those criteria.

Comment: Look closely at the plot, for instance the red portion of 4 overlaps with the bar below it. This is more noticeable in plots with more bars, and with enough bars becomes nearly illegible.

Comment: what happens if you save the figure with the `dpi` parameter set higher?

Comment: Setting the dpi to 1000 does not seem to improve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This artifact is also visible with matplotlib defaults if you set the bar linewidth to what seaborn style has:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 3))
df.plot(stacked=True, width=1, kind="barh", lw=.5)
```

[image]

A solution would be to increase the bar lines back to roughly where the matplotlib defaults are:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 3))
df.plot(stacked=True, width=1, kind="barh", lw=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Interestingly this problem seems to go away regardless of the line width I specify, which I'm not sure I entirely understand. This does fix the issue though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should reduce the line width?

```
import seaborn as sns

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, width=1, lw=0.1, ax=ax)
```

[image]