# Stacked bar chart changes x axis plot number values

Tags: python, pandas, plot

**Question:**

If I choose the `plot` option `stacked = False` I get the correct x axis output for my data.

[image: false stacked]

However, when I use `stacked = True` I get incorrect output showing higher (incorrect) values on the  x axis.  Nothing else has changed apart from the `stacked` option.

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Data**

`DataFrame.to_dict()` output [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/74mndquzkky09je/plot_data.txt?dl=0)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

cols = ['OpenToLast','OpenToMaxHigh','OpenToMaxLow']
colors = {'OpenToLast':'b', 'OpenToMaxHigh' : '#CCD1F5', 'OpenToMaxLow': '#C6DAF4'}


axnum = auction[cols].plot(kind='barh',
                        figsize=(6,8),   
                        fontsize=9,
                        color=[colors[i] for i in cols],
                        edgecolor = "none",   
                        stacked = False,  
                        legend = True)

axnum.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
plt.axvline(0, color='B')
```

Comment: Stacked plot stacks the individual bars on top of each other rather than overlapping the data. For eg, your top value at 2016-12-16 is 25(open to last), 30(open to max high) which in stacked plot is 25 and 30 stacked together at 55

Comment: @VaishaliGarg please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stacked plot stacks the individual bars on top of each other rather than overlapping the data. For eg, your top value at 2016-12-16 is 25(open to last), 30(open to max high) which in stacked plot is 25 and 30 stacked together at 55

Comment: very neat answer!

Comment: Thank you.  So there is no way to keep the `stacked = True` visual appearance and the `stacked =  False` x values?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185427/prevent-overlapping-bars-using-seaborn-with-pandas-plotting

Answer (score 2):

They're not actually higher, they're just stacked on top of each other.

For example, in your first graph, your top bar `2016-12-16 11:30:00` - the `OpenToLast` value is 25 and the `OpenToMaxHigh` value is 31.

However when stacked=True, they still have the same values, but they are relative to one another. Whilst, `OpenToLast` is still 25, your `OpenToMaxHigh` value looks as if it is going from 0 to 56, but it's actually starting from where `OpenToLast` ends: i.e. it goes from 25 to 56, which is its correct value (31).

I think that might be the "obvious" thing you were missing, just my two cents.

Comment: Hi, yes it was the obvious thing I was missing.  +1 thanks